# How to calculate variables from the frontend using python/django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm building a python/django portfolio and I'm having a very hard time with one of my Gym/BMI calculator.

I'm trying to have a user input their current Weight and Height, so they can have a BMI result that will be visible from the frontend, then POST and them saved from the Backend models.

I just don't know how to include a .py function that I created that will allow the user to input their details (Weight and Height) from the frontend and have calculations done on the webpage and have results displayed in a textfield...

My models is as follows

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here. (<-- This is my Model, where i'll save the calculation)

class BMI(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Weight = models.IntegerField()
    Height = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

```
# Create your forms here. (<-- This is my form, where user will be inputting their Weight and Height)
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from . models import BMI

class BMIForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BMI
        fields = ['Weight', 'Height']
```

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import BMI
from . forms import BMIForm

# Create your views here.
def Home(request):
    BMIOutcome = BMIForm
    return render(request, 'Experiment/Home.html',
    {'BMIOutcome':BMIOutcome})
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to render ModelForm in html?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Comment: Hi @SunderamDubey. My apologies for the lack to clarity. I want to be able to perform calculations (BMI Result = Weight * Height) on the html page, using python functions. 

I want the user to enter their Weight and Height on the webpage and after they click on "Calculate" button, the output will be displayed and those details must be saved on the backend on the python model.

Answer (score -1):

I have decided the best outcome will be to use Javascript for that kind of calcualation.